# PHP compute total of nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I have this example array. I wanted to compute for the total the areas then add it to the parent total plus the location's individual total. So First location total will be "11" because 7 + 4. Then the "State" parent will do the same also so 10(1st state parent) + 11 (1st child) + 10 (2nd child) = 31.

```
    $arr = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'state', 'total' => '10', 
            'location' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'location', 'total' => '4', 
                    'area' => array(
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '6'), 
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '1')
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'location', 'total' => '5', 
                    'area' => array(
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '2'), 
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '3')
                    )
                )
            )
        ), 

        array(
            'type' => 'state', 'total' => '20', 
            'location' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'location', 'total' => '4', 
                    'area' => array(
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '8'), 
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '7')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

The desired correct output now should be recreated as:

```
    $arr_FINAL = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'state', 'total' => '31', 
            'location' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'location', 'total' => '11', 
                    'area' => array(
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '6'), 
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '1')
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'location', 'total' => '10', 
                    'area' => array(
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '2'), 
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '3')
                    )
                )
            )
        ), 

        array(
            'type' => 'state', 'total' => '39', 
            'location' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'location', 'total' => '19', 
                    'area' => array(
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '8'), 
                        array('type' => 'area', 'total' => '7')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

On-going unfinished solution as per CBroe's request:

```
        // country > state > location > area
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            foreach ($v['location'] as $k2 => $v2) {
                foreach ($v2['area'] as $k3 => $v3) {
                    echo $v3['total'] . ",";
                    $ctr_area[] = $v3['total'];

                }
                $arr2[$k]['location'][$k2]['total'] += array_sum($ctr_area);
                $ctr_location[] = $v2['total'];
                $ctr_area = array();
            }
            $arr2[$k]['total'] += array_sum($ctr_location);

            $ctr_state[] = $v['total'];
            $ctr_location = array();
        }
```

Comment: that's a very specific set of data, would probably need specific functionality. I would not waste time and effort on making a dynamic solution. First getting it working, then make it better.

Comment: So you just dropping your requirements here and not even showing the slightest bit of an approach ... is that the _“passion to challenge sophisticated logic problem”_ you talk about on your profile?

Comment: @CBroe I'm multi tasking. I posted this question then proceeded to do it. My current solution so far is "check updated question" :)

Comment: @marknt15 Provide your code, then, so that we can take it from where you are stuck instead of throwing the solution. You surely already know that, seeing your reputation in this section.

Comment: @ksjohn I just provided my on-going code at the bottom of the question. Next time I will add the on-going own solution with the question.

Comment: @marknt15 check the answer posted... I tried in on a php fiddle it works... Hope it suits the purpose...

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu thanks it worked. I already tested it with different values. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){ 
$state_total = $arr[$i]["total"];    
for($j = 0; $j < count($arr[$i]['location']); $j++){
    $location_total = $arr[$i]['location'][$j]["total"];
    for($k = 0; $k < count($arr[$i]['location'][$j]['area']); $k++){
        if(isset($arr[$i]['location'][$j]['area'][$k])){
            $location_total = $location_total + $arr[$i]['location'][$j]['area'][$k]['total'];
        }
    }
    $arr[$i]['location'][$j]["total"] = $location_total;
    $state_total = $state_total + $location_total;
}
$arr[$i]["total"] = $state_total;
}
```

Hope it helps.